# Is it possible to install py26-mysql without installing mysql5 package?

Tags: python, mysql, macports

I am developing a database based django application and I have installed apache, python and django using macport on a snow leopard machine. I ran into issues installing MySQL with macport. But I was able to successfully install a standalone MySQL server (from MySQL.com). Is it possible to remove the MysQL package installed along with py26-MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use py26-mysql you don't need the entire server distribution for MySQL. You do need the client libs, at the very least. If you remove the server, you need to make sure you re-install the base libraries needed by the Python module to function.

Comment: How do I install just py26-mysql without the server or remove the server after installing py26-mysql?

Thanks